# How to join array of documents from array of _ids in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, mongodb

I have a document inside of MongoDb that has an array of ObjectIds. Looks like this:

```
--Shops Collection--

listing_ids: [
ObjectId("6092f741ccb0d55ba444883e"),
ObjectId("6092f741ccb0d55ba444883f"),
ObjectId("6092f741ccb0d55ba4448840"),
ObjectId("6092f741ccb0d55ba4448841")
],
...
```

and I have a listing document like this:

```
--Listings Collection--

_id: ObjectId("6092f741ccb0d55ba444883e"),
...
```

How do I join the listings documents onto the shops document that contains the arrays? I have tried the "$lookup" operator from MonogoDb but can't get it to work. I'm always hit with a FailedToParse error. This is what the "$lookup" looks like:

```
const collection = client.db("development").collection("shops");

    const shop = await collection.aggregate([
      { 
        "$lookup": {
        "from": "listings",
        "localfield": "listing_ids",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "listings"
      }}
    ]).toArray();
```

This is expected to return all of the shops documents with the corresponding listings documents in an array called `listings`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I almost had it right. I ended up using the MongoDB Atlas Aggregation tool and it helped me. This is the working pipeline:

```
.aggregate([
        {
          '$lookup': {
            'from': 'listings', 
            'localField': 'listing_ids', 
            'foreignField': '_id', 
            'as': 'listings'
          }
        }, {
          '$lookup': {
            'from': 'listings', 
            'localField': 'highlightedListings', 
            'foreignField': '_id', 
            'as': 'highlightedListings'
          }
        }
      ]).toArray();
```